# How to wait until Vimeo.accessToken method finishes. Thought to use Q?

Tags: node.js, vimeo-api

I'm writing a small app in node.js that interfaces with Vimeo's API.  I installed the official Node SDK from vimeo using `npm install vimeo-api`.  Everything is working fine, but now I want to change the program flow to be more "promise like".  For example, I would like for my program to wait until it receives the OAuth access token returned by the Vimeo.accessToken method before it executes any new code.  How can I acheive this?

Here is some code driving the retrieval of the access token--very much taken from the examples on the SDK github page:

```
var vmoapi = require('vimeo-api'),
    vmo = new vmoapi(VMO_CLIENT_ID, VMO_CLIENT_SECRET);
    .
    .
    .

function getAccessToken(code, redirectURI){

    vmo.accessToken(code, redirectURI, function(err, token){

        if (err) { 
            console.log("Vimeo API Error\n" + err);
            return;
        }

        if (token.access_token){

            console.log(nutil.inspect(token));
            vmo.access_token = token.access_token;
            user = token.user;
            userScopes = token.scope;

            return token;

        }

    })
}
```

In node.js how can I do something like the following:

```
getAccessToken(myCode, "http://someplace.com").done(function(data){
     console.log("Access token" + nutil.inspect(data));
})
```

I thought maybe I would use Kris Kowal's Q library, but am not certain about how to go about implementing it so that my app flows in the manner that I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after reading Q's documentation and some examples, here is what I implemented and it seems to be working!

```
var vmoapi = require('vimeo-api'),
    vmo = new vmoapi(VMO_CLIENT_ID, VMO_CLIENT_SECRET),
    .
    .
    .
    deferred =  Q.deferred();

 .
 .
 .

 function getAccessToken(code, redirectURI) {

      vmo.accessToken(code, redirectURI, function(err, token) {

             if (err) {
                console.log("Vimeo API Error\b" + err);
                deferred.reject(new Error(err));
             }

             if (token.access_token){
                vmo.access_token = token.access_token;
                user = token.user;
                userScopes = token.scope;

                deferred.resolve(token);
             }
      })

      return deferred.promise;
 }

getAccessToken(parsedURL.query.code, vmoRedirectURI)
              .then(function(data){
                       console.log("Vimeo access token:\n" + nutil.inspect(data))
               });
```

The solution involves use the `Q.deferred()` object and then setting up the `.reject` and `.resolve` methods within the Vimeo.accessToken callback function.  Then at the end of the function that calls the Vimeo.accessToken method, return the `deferred.promise`.